# Calculated variance of beta coefficients in OLS don't match experimental value

Tags: regression, machine-learning, variance

I'm trying to understand what is meant by the variance of beta in ordinary least squares.
If $\pmb{\beta} = (X^{T}X)^{-1}X^Ty $

my textbook states that $\textbf{var} (\beta_j) = \sigma^2 \sqrt{(X^{T}X)^{-1}_{jj}}$

I set up an experiment to check this out, generating data from $y = 1.5x^2 + 2x + 2.05$ + noise

```
def make_data(n):
    x = np.linspace(0,10, n)
    true_value =  1.5*x**2 + 2*x + 2.05 
    y = true_value + np.random.normal(0, 3.1, n)

    # Set up design matrix
    D = np.ones((n,3))
    D[:,1] = x
    D[:,2] = x**2
    return D, y
```

Then estimating the variance of the noise, and calculating the variance of $\beta$ from the given formula as such:

```
# Find variance of betas using 1 experiment

n = 100
x, y = make_data(n)
xtx_inv = np.linalg.inv(x.T@x)

# Ordinary least squares
beta = xtx_inv @ x.T @ y

y_predict = x @ beta
error = y - y_predict

# estimate sigma squared
sigma2 = (error.T @ error) / (n-3.0)

# estimate variance of beta
var_beta = np.zeros(3)
for i in range(3):
    var_beta[i] = sigma2 * np.sqrt(xtx_inv[i,i])

print(var_beta)

[2.70019636 1.24796411 0.12075855]
```

Now, if I were to repeat this many times, I would expect that the variance in the different $\beta$'s generated would be close to the calculated numbers.
However,

```
# Find m values for beta using m experiments
m = 1000
n = 100
betas = np.zeros((m, 3))

for i in range(m):
    x, y = make_data(n)
    xtx_inv = np.linalg.inv(x.T@x)
    beta = xtx_inv @ x.T @ y
    betas[i,:] = beta

print(np.var(betas, axis=0))
[0.85806279 0.18024798 0.00165654]
```

Why are these variances not close to each other?

Have I just misunderstood the interpretation of  $\textbf{var} (\beta_j) = \sigma^2 \sqrt{(X^{T}X)^{-1}_{jj}}$ ?

Thanks!

Comment: You seem to have merged two different formulas, one for the variance and the other for the standard error. If you want the variance, remove the square root; if you want the SE, use $\sigma$ instead of $\sigma^2.$

Comment: Thanks, removing the square root seems to solve it, I was just blindly following an article that said an estimate for the variance of the j'th regression coefficient was as stated above

Comment: Even peer-reviewed articles can have typos.  A good check in this case (and in many other instances) is to evaluate the units of measurement.  For instance, if the regressors are in hours and the response is in kilometers, then the coefficients must be in kilometers per hour, $X^\prime X$ will be squared hours, its inverse will be per squared hour, and $\sigma^2$ must be in square km. Thus, your formula would give squared kilometers per squared hour on the left and (square km) * sqrt(per square hr) = (square km) per hour, an evident disagreement.